# WIndows 11 continues to Update, even after pausing

Tags: windows-11, windows-update

I recently started a powershell scripting job that I expect to take several days (large database rebuild and restore)

Prior to this I disabled windows updates for a couple of weeks.

After a couple of days the server re-booted during the night - screwing up the powershell script.

The event log includes this...

```
Date     : 17/09/2023 01:30:14
Computer : localhost
EventID  : 1074
Action   : restart
Reason   : Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
Message  : The process C:\windows\uus\packages\preview\AMD64\MoUsoCoreWorker.exe (MYSERVER) has initiated the restart of computer MYSERVER on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
Reason Code: 0x80020010
Shut-down Type: restart
Comment: 
User     : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

It appears that despite window updates being paused till 5th Oct the server installed a new update and rebooted during the night. Exactly what I didn't want it to do!
I've browsed thought the event log around this time, and can't spot any other reason for a restart (nothing obvious anyway).
What might have caused this, and is there any other way to pause updates (or more specifically) prevent re-booting.

Comment: How exactly did you pause Windows Updates? Setting your connection as a metered connector won’t work in a corporate environment

Comment: @Ramhound - I selected 'settings' then 'windows update' then 'pause updates' then selected the period for which it was to be paused.

Comment: That isn’t enough to disable Windows Update in a corporate environment. Have your Administrator disable it properly for you

Comment: I am the administrator! I'm looking to pause it for a view weeks, not disable it

Answer (score -1):

Windows keeps on evolving new rules for forcing Windows Updates
in the name of security, so methods for blocking them need also
to evolve.
(Whatever advice I give may become irrelevant some time in the future.)

The best way I have found to prevent Windows from downloading
updates is to set your network adapter to metered:

- Run *Settings > Network & Internet > Status*
- Click Properties under your network name
- Click under "Set as metered connection" to turn it to On.

A method for disabling automatic updates is :

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Position to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update*
- Double-click "Configure Automatic Updates" and set it to Disabled.

A forceful method is in the Services applet to set the
"Windows Update" service to disabled.
Note that this setting might get undone after a reboot.